# Comparison of a `float` to `np.nan` in Spark Dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark, nan

Is this expected behaviour? I thought to raise an issue with Spark, but this seems such a basic functionality, that it's hard to imagine that there's a bug here. What am I missing?

**Python**

```python
import numpy as np

>>> np.nan < 0.0
False

>>> np.nan > 0.0
False
```

**PySpark**

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df = spark.createDataFrame([(np.nan, 0.0),(0.0, np.nan)])
df.show()
#+---+---+
#| _1| _2|
#+---+---+
#|NaN|0.0|
#|0.0|NaN|
#+---+---+

df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- _1: double (nullable = true)
# |-- _2: double (nullable = true)

df.select(col("_1")> col("_2")).show()
#+---------+
#|(_1 > _2)|
#+---------+
#|     true|
#|    false|
#+---------+
```

Comment: It seems likely that they're using something like `Double.compare` to make sorting work in the presence of NaNs, resulting in the `true` value you see, but I haven't found any documentation on the matter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is both expected and documented behavior. To quote [NaN Semantics](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-reference.html#nan-semantics) section of the official [Spark SQL Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html) (emphasis mine):

> There is specially handling for not-a-number (NaN) when dealing with float or double types that does not exactly match standard floating point semantics. Specifically:
>
> - NaN = NaN returns true.
> - In aggregations, all NaN values are grouped together.
> - NaN is treated as a normal value in join keys.
> - **NaN values go last when in ascending order, larger than any other numeric value**.

AdAs you see ordering behavior is not the only difference, compared to Python NaN. In particular Spark considers NaN's equal:

```
spark.sql("""
    WITH table AS (SELECT CAST('NaN' AS float) AS x, cast('NaN' AS float) AS y) 
    SELECT x = y, x != y FROM table
""").show()
```

```
+-------+-------------+
|(x = y)|(NOT (x = y))|
+-------+-------------+
|   true|        false|
+-------+-------------+
```

while plain Python

```
float("NaN") == float("NaN"), float("NaN") != float("NaN")
```

```
(False, True)
```

and NumPy

```
np.nan == np.nan, np.nan != np.nan
```

```
(False, True)
```

don't.

You can check [`eqNullSafe` docstring](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/7043aee1ba95e92e1cbd0ebafcc5b09b69ee3082/python/pyspark/sql/column.py#L180-L229) for additional examples.

So to get desired result you'll have to explicitly check for NaN's

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, isnan, when

when(isnan("_1") | isnan("_2"), False).otherwise(col("_1") > col("_2"))
```

Comment: `np.nan` and `float("NaN")` - aren't they the same thing (even they aren't technically equal to each other)?